# List indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, html, integer, web-scraping

I searched for this problem and tried using the solutions above, but none of them appeared to work.

My current code is:

```
 for item in g_data:
     print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[[1], [2], [3]]['href']
```

This results in `TypeError: indices must be integers, not tuple`.

How can I fix this?, I know its a simple problem, but the solutions I tried result in it either coming up and saying 'not list', 'not str' or 'not tuple'.

Comment: Try to separate [ [1], [2], [3] ] into items....find_all(....)[1] then [2] then [3]

Comment: What's `g_data` type?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso You mean like this

print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[[1][2][3]]['href']

This results in a list index out of range

Comment: In general when this happens try spreading it over multiple lines so that you can see where the exact TypeError is originating from.

Comment: `[1], [2], [3]` is a `tuple`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thats the weird thing, individually they all work

If you mean try them like :
print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[1]['href'] 

However I don't want to have to repeat the code over and over again, and when I try to make a list of multiple integers it doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterWood can it be a tuple in square brackets?

Comment: @AlperTuran 

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"id": "resultsCol"})

Comment: If you're trying to get the second, third, and fourth item from a list, the proper syntax is not `my_list[[1],[2],[3]]`, it's `my_list[1:4]`. And if you're trying to get the `href` value from each item in a list of dictionaries, the proper syntax is not `my_list_of_dicts["href"]`, it's `[d["href"] for d in my_list_of_dicts]`.

Comment: @kevin i'm not, I was using those as a test, I only want to get the href values from [1],[7],[13].. (X=+6). Hope that helps more.

Comment: You should be able to use Kevin's solution with the range 1,7,13... if you write `[d['href'] for d in item.contents[1].find_all('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal'})[1::6]]` I'm a bit surprised though, that Cica's answer does not work. Maybe we miss some information?

Answer (score 0):

So i've completely solved the problem at hand by circumventing the selection issue.

Heres what I did:

> for item in g_data:
>       print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"})[0]["href"]

What this does is first searches the main content on the page (any url could be in G_data). Next it will select [1] which is the focus content, products, images, links etc. It gets rid of all the other stuff. Then there is the part within the brackets, what this does is it selects this piece of content

> Gorilla Tape 11m

Now there its not selecting just that one, it selecting all the products on the page. After that there is [0] this the selection of the first product, so if there are 15 products on the page this is 0.

Then you have the ["href"] what this does is take just the data within that keyword, in this case the url for product page in question.

By doing it in this method, you could either select the code and paste and have it look like this:

> print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"})[0]["href"]
>       print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"})[1]["href"]
>       print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"})[2]["href"]

Or you could find a way to list all the products from X-Y in one line of code, which shouldn't be to difficult.

Answer (score -1):

If this works

`print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[1]['href']`

that is correct, you just assign an integer as an index. I guess you want to do this.

```
for item in g_data:
     print [item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"})[index]['href'] for index in [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however it just results in a invalid syntax, due to the for statement.

Comment: @JamieMumford Ah, sorry, I missed one close bracket in the end. I've corrected it, let me now if it works or no.

Comment: No it doesn't work either, for some reason its the 'for' statement.

Comment: Maybe next time you should explain your problem in better way with the complete data structure, instead of asking people to guess what is really the problem and remove other people's reputation who are trying to help. Just saying.